# WP Query for variable taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, array

I am stuck with this. Maybe its simple, maybe its not. But there goes.

I understand that the standard way of querying multiple taxonomies in wordpress is using the method described here.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

However, this way only allows for "hardcoded" taxonomies.

**What I'd like to achieve is run the query for multiple variable taxonomies.**

So assume I have my array of taxonomies via:

`$taxes = get_taxonomies( array('public' => true ) , 'names', 'and' );`

Trying to pass the `$taxes` variable directly does not work as `'taxonomy'` does not accept arrays. e.g.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxes,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Therefore I tried to work around this by first attempting:

```
foreach ($taxes as $tax) {
    $the_taxes[] = array (  
        'taxonomy' => $tax,
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $terms,
    );
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    $the_taxes                  
    ),
);
```

This did not work, I guess because `$the_taxes` variable is itself an array of arrays. I even tried to give it a stripped version of the array output without the array() wrap to imitate exactly the same output as if I had followed the standard wordpress way of hardcoding the taxonomies to be queried.

```
$the_other_taxes = substr(print_r($the_taxes,true),19,-2);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        $the_other_taxes                    
    ),
);
```

Still no luck..

Is there a workaround for this problem? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks a lot,
Harry

Comment: Maybe declare it like this: `$the_taxes = array( 'relation' => 'OR' )` and keep your `foreach` the same, then just `'tax_query' => $the_taxes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tax_query` requires an array of arrays, and `$the_taxes` is an array of arrays, you've already got 99% of your answer.

```
foreach ($taxes as $tax) {
    $the_taxes[] = array (  
        'taxonomy' => $tax,
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $terms,
    );
}

$the_taxes['relation'] = 'OR';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => $the_taxes,
);
```

Comment: That was quick and spot on!!! Thanks a lot for making it THAT simple ;-)